# Adding VBox to MenuButton JavaFX

Tags: javafx, fxml

I am having a problem with inserting the VBox into MenuButton as child property, since I have to do this in the assignment. So far I have come up with this:

```html
 <MenuButton fx:id="mb" mnemonicParsing="false" text="" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
        <items>
            <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" >
                <Button text="Button" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
                <RadioButton text="RadioButton" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
                <Button text="Click Me" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                <ComboBox GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                <Slider GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                <CheckBox text="CheckBox" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                <TextField  prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
            </VBox>
        </items>
      </MenuButton>
```

But I have received the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to coerce VBox@13f6e35e to class javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.
```

Can somebody clarify my mistake or help me solve it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: A pretty strange assignmeent. Are you sure you're not supposed to add multiple `MenuItem` subtypes like `CheckMenuItem` ect? BTW the gridpane indices are of no use if the node is not a child of a `GridPane`.

Comment: Yeah, it is kinda strange, but the main goal for it is to shrink the layout into the menuitem of menubutton, as much sense as this makes. So it has to have the same layout in the menubutton when shrinked.

Answer (score 8):

You are trying to add a `VBox` to the `MenuButton`, which only accepts a `MenuItem` as a child.

You can get around that by using a `CustomMenuItem` instead. The `CustomMenuItem` allows you to add any arbitrary `Node` as its `graphic` property, including a VBox.

So you could do something like this instead:

**FXML:**

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0"
      prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <MenuButton mnemonicParsing="false" text="MenuButton">
        <items>
            <CustomMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Unspecified Action">
                <graphic>
                    <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" spacing="5.0">
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button"/>
                        <RadioButton mnemonicParsing="false" text="RadioButton"/>
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Click Me"/>
                        <ComboBox prefWidth="150.0"/>
                        <Slider/>
                        <CheckBox text="Check Box"/>
                        <TextField/>
                    </VBox>
                </graphic>
            </CustomMenuItem>
        </items>
    </MenuButton>
</VBox>
```

**Java:**

```
    MenuButton menuButton = new MenuButton();

    VBox menuVbox = new VBox();
    menuVbox.getChildren().addAll(
            new Button("Button"),
            new RadioButton("RadioButton"),
            new Button("Click Me"),
            new ComboBox<>(),
            new Slider(),
            new CheckBox("CheckBox"),
            new TextField()
    );
    CustomMenuItem vboxMenuItem = new CustomMenuItem(menuVbox);

    menuButton.getItems().add(vboxMenuItem);
```

> On a side note, any time you see an `IllegalArgumentException`, your first stop should be the JavaDocs for the class in question (in this case, `MenuItem`).